# How to retain dynamically added checkbox on page refresh in angular Js?

Tags: angularjs

I have 4 checkboxes for students name.I am trying to add students name on click of Add button.The student name is getting added long with checkbox but it goes off on page refresh showing the default 4 checkboxes.Is there any way around to retain the student's name on page refresh using local storage.I would like to delete the added name only when i click on delete button.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: Please add some code you have already build and what you have tried to do with localStorage that doesn't work. Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you could use localstorage to store your colection of checkboxes or if you going to do anything with them, save them on the server ...

Comment: "Is there any way around to retain the student's name on page refresh using local storage" - yes, there are many possible ways to do this with localstorage.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev could you please let me know?This is the first time i am gonna implement local storage concept in angularjs.I know the simple message to be displayed using local storage.But here the first 4 values are coming from JSON and the one i am adding is getting added to JSON.Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you tend to store information in local storage, then you have to make sure you update it at the time of both addition and deletion.

### Addition

```
function addName(index,name)
    var studentInfo = {
     "index" : index,
      "name" : name
    }
    var studentCollection = [];

    var data = localStorage.getItem("information");
    if(data !== undefined) {
        studentCollection = JSON.parse(data);    
    }
    studentCollection.push(studentInfo);
    localStorage.setItem("information", JSON.stringify(studentCollection));
}
```

### Deletion

```
    function deleteName(index,name)
        var data = localStorage.getItem("information");
        if(data !== undefined) {
            var studentCollection = JSON.parse(data);
            for(var i = 0; i < studentCollection.length; i++ ) {
                if(studentCollection[i].index === index && studentCollection[i].name === name) {
                    studentCollection.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
            localStorage.setItem("information", JSON.stringify(studentCollection));
        }


    }
```